# How to wait for a process in a JS NPM script using ShellJS

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, npm-scripts, shelljs

Node version:
**v.10.15.3**

ShellJS version:
**0.8.3**

Operating system:
**Windows 10**

Is it possible to wait for a process to finish and then start another one using the wait command in a windows system in a NodeJS script?

I have tried the below, there are no errors, but the echoes are not printed and the script `some_npm_script` is not executed, is it possible? like I did below? This works in a Linux machine BTW.

Commands like `shell.exec(truncate -s 0 ./somefile.js)` works and but I do not see the `truncate` command in the source on the ShellJS module.

```
shell.exec(`
echo "Installing"
yarn add some_npm_package &
pid=$!
wait $pid
echo "Done installing"
yarn some_npm_script
`);
```

Any assistance is appreciated, any explanation on why it is not working or any solution or resources, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved my goal by moving that specific piece of code into a bash/sh NPM script, and then I have used the `shell.exec` function froom `shellJS` to execute the bash NPM script in the JS NPM script like:

```
shell.exec(yarn bash_npm_script_name) // the script that uses the wait command
```

So this worked for me, it waited for the package to be installed and then run a script after it was finished.